# How to remove tables from dataset using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have dataset which contains two tables i want to remove the first table from dataset using vb.net when trying to remove throwing error saying that "Expression doesnot produce a value".

code is as ds.Tables.Remove("Table")

Comment: `ds.Tables.Remove("Table")` is valid VB and will not produce the error you mentioned. Please edit the question and add all **relevant** code for a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Or you can remove by index like this: `ds.Tables.RemoveAt(0)`